# Redux principles seem to contradict

Tags: redux

Maybe someone can explain this to me, but these two principles, in my opinion, contradict each other and it's really hampering my progress in learning Redux.

**State is *read-only*** and ***Changes* are made with pure functions**

The first line after *State is read-only* is this: "The only way to mutate the state...". If something is read-only then it shouldn't be able to be mutated in the first place. Even in the Egghead videos the states are always labeled as `const`, but are still changed defeating the purpose of `const`.

Can someone please explain to me how these are not diametrically opposed ideas?

Comment: state isn't read-only, it is immutable.  As in "immutable data structures".

Comment: Can you link to the article you're reading?

Comment: Also, from MDN: "The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned." Just FYI

Comment: @JoshBeam http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html

Comment: Read-only here means that the "state object" is immutable. If the state wasn't changeable then we won't need javascript anymore. It's just the javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

The state is read-only, as far as the world outside Redux is concerned. Think of it as a view on the append-only sequence of application events (actions) that have happened. You can generate new actions, and those will result in the state becoming different.

Of course, it's the real world and there is mutability *somewhere*. As Rich Hickey famously put it:

> “If a tree falls in the woods, does it make a sound? If a pure
>   function mutates data to produce an immutable value, is that ok?” ~
>   @richhickey

But as much as is practically possible, you write your application without directly mutating things. Instead, you describe the changes you would like to see (dispatching actions), and a framework (Redux) carries them out, using your reducers to create the entire view of the store (the state) at once, and through React's `props`, a new view is generated as a result.

This is inspired by the concept of functional reactive programming. In this paradigm, all functions are pure, and you handle the concept of change over time by representing "what you would do with a value, if it were to have changed". In some sense, you conceptualize the entire past and future of a variable as an immutable function, whose future you simply happen not to know yet. Sorry if that got too philosophical.

Comment: So if state is only read only to everything _but_ Redux, I don't understand why it isn't stated that way. In fact, it's stated that it is _always_ read-only.

Comment: @StevenWade Don't know what to tell you :) You can see right here in the source what happens, clear as day: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L121. I think you make a fair case that the docs could be more explicit. The author's active on here, and seems like a reasonable dude. Maybe open an issue on the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1):

There's no contradiction, though certainly the confusion is understandable.

A good way to think about it is to draw an analogy between React state and Redux state.

In React, you only ever define your component state once, in the `constructor()` or `getInitialState()` method. From that point on, you always treat `this.state` as read-only, you never assign anything to `this.state`. To change the state, you call `this.setState()`.

The same is true in Redux. You define the state - or each different part of the state - once. Typically it's called `initialState` and assigned as the default value of the `state` parameter of your reducer. Treating `state` as read-only means never overwriting or mutating the state. The only way to change the state is with the return value of your reducer.

#### Or, in short...

I think your real hang up is over the state being both changeable and read-only, so let me be more pithy:

A CD-ROM is read only, but I can eject the CD and replace it with another.

Comment: So when you say treat state as read-only, you really just mean only part of your app treats it that way. Just from watching the egghead videos, I can see that state is not always read-only. Your reducer can do something like: `return state + 1`. Even using `Object.assign`. You are still altering state. This is not read-only. Also this makes the CD-ROM analogy wrong because you'd have to copy whats on the old disc and then add to the new one.

I hate to be nit-picky, but I still don't see this as read-only.

Comment: I mean just `Object.assign`

Comment: The reducer has an input parameter named `state` and it never changes that parameter, it returns a new state. Whether that's based on the old state or not is beside the point. Conceptually `return state + 1` differs from `state = state + 1`. Used properly, `Object.assign` reads and copies, it doesn't overwrite. That's what is meant by readonly.